# Pass .sql file into DBI::dbGetQuery with comments as the first line into R / RStudio

Tags: r, odbc, r-dbi

I am trying to pass a `.sql` file into `DBI::dbGetQuery`, but I run into problems whenever there is comment in the first line. For example:

**runs_fine.sql**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

**does_not_work.sql**

```
-- Some comment
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

Then in R:

```
library(odbc)
library(tidyverse)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "my_connection")
dbGetQuery(con, read_file("sql/runs_fine.sql")) # success
dbGetQuery(con, read_file("sql/does_not_work.sql")) # fails
```

Motivation: I would like to leverage the convenient [sql preview function from `RStudio`](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/10/02/rstudio-1-2-preview-sql/), but this requires the first line be the following for any `.sql` file:

`-- !preview conn=con`

...which causes the `dbGetQuery` to fail. I suppose a workaround would be to use some sort of read.file function that can skip lines or avoid comment lines.

*NOTE: If a comment line is in the middle of a `.sql` file, `dbGetQuery` succeeds as expected and avoids the appropriate commented lines.*

---

DBMS is CHD Impala, kerberized. The return value from `read_file()` begins with:

`"-- !preview conn=con\r\n\r\nSELECT \r\n    ..."`

Comment: What is the return from `read_file` here? If I test with (for instance) a SQLite connection, I can do `DBI::dbGetQuery(con0, "-- ignore\nselect 1 as a")` without error. (And I've tested with `odbc()` connections as well, not just SQLite.)

Comment: Perhaps two better questions: to what DBMS are you connecting, and what is the error you get? I've tested with SQLite (`RSQLite`), Postgres (both `RPostgres` and `odbc`), and SQL Server (`odbc`).

Comment: @r2evans Apologize, should have clarified DBMS is CDH -- Impala / Hive, Kerberized if that matters.

Comment: @r2evans, I am able to get around this by chaining the `.sql` file into some string replacements: `file.sql %>% str_replace_all("--.*|\r|\n")` but this seems silly because when a comment is in the middle this is not required. It might have to do with how DBI is passing this to Impala. Likely via `impala-shell` but have not been able reproduce the error via the shell.

Comment: That pattern can produce false positive matches, though some of them are admittedly contrived. Do you have access through any other interface in order to test if this is specific to this DBMS? Regardless, if you are really only concerned about "leading comments" (and mid-query comments are understood correctly), then perhaps `gsub("^\\s*--([^\n\r]*)[\n\r]", "", qry)` works? The `\\s*` matches zero or more whitespace, which includes `\n` and `\r` (if that's important ... I think it is) and then the two dashes, removing anything after the dashes until the first newline/linefeed.